# How to make fasterxml ObjectMapper work with codehaus annotations

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using the `ObjectMapper` class from the `fasterxml` package (`com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper`) to serialize some POJOs.

The problem I'm facing is that all the annotations in the POJOs are from the older codehaus library. The `fasterxml` `ObjectMapper` is not recognizing the codehaus jackson annotations.
One possible solution is to update the annotations in the POJO to `fasterxml`, but the POJOs are provided by a third party, hence I cannot modify it.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I you need to use older version of library... then use older version of `ObjectMapper` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide your own [AnnotationIntrospector](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/AnnotationIntrospector.html) to process old annotation.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setAnnotationIntrospector(new MyAnnotationIntrospector());
```

You can also checkout the [jackson-legacy-introspector](https://github.com/Laures/jackson-legacy-introspector) listed on the jackson github. It's an existing implementation of AnnotationIntrospector for old annotations.

Answer (score -1):

If you can use workaround with inheritance

```
// Original class doesn't need to be modified
class Customer {
     @org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty("first_name")
     String firstName;
}

class CustomerWrapper extends Customer {
     @com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty("first_name")
     String firstName;
}
```

And in code use CustomerWrapper class which will be serialized correctly